# Trying to delete the currently viewed item in the details item page with a command

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TasksGroup which contains mutiple Tasks.

My ListView is made of Tasks.

Currently when i click a Tasks, its TasksDetailsPage opens. This page has a delete button which will be linked to DeleteTaskCommand and when it's clicked i want to delete the current Task that is viewed and go back to main screen.

My problem is that i'm not sure how i can pass the current selected task when i click the item in the listview to my TasksDetailsPage ( in the OnItemSelected method just under).

**OnItemSelected method in TasksGroupPage**

```
        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage()

                {
                    BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Tasks
                    
                });
            }
}
```

I think i need to somehow pass (i think i need the current selected Task) to my DetailsPage :

**TasksDetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class TasksDetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TasksDetailsPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }


        }
}
```

**Then i can delete in my TasksDetailsPageViewModel.cs**

```
public Command DeleteTaskCommand { get; set; }

        public TasksDetailsPageViewModel()
        {
            
            DeleteTaskCommand = new Command(async () => await DeleteTask(), () => !IsBusy);
            
        }

        async Task DeleteTask()
        {
            bool isUserAccept = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Détails de la tâche", "Supprimer la tâche", "OK", "Cancel");

            if(isUserAccept)
            {
                await App.Database.DeleteTaskAsync(Tasks);
            }
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
}
```

**Database table if needed.**

```
    public class Tasks
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(TasksGroup))]
        public int TasksGroupID { get; set; }
        public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }
        public string TaskDuration { get; set; }
        public string TaskDBA { get; set; }
        public string TaskComment { get; set; }

        [ManyToOne]
        public TasksGroup TasksGroup { get; set; }

    }

    public class TasksGroup
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string TasksGroupDescription { get; set; }

        public DateTime TasksGroupDate { get; set; } 
        
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<Tasks> Taches { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For how to use command, you could check the link below.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass it via the constructor

```
var task = e.SelectedItem as Tasks;
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage(task));
```

then in the page constructor

```
Tasks task;

public TasksDetailsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent(Tasks task);

        this.task = task;
    }
```

Comment: your VM contains your data/model - your page should bind to the VM and access any data fields via the VM.